# Import JSON dataset to R

Tags: r, json

I want to make a data frame from the following JSON sample:

```
{"gender": "M", "age": 68, "id": "e2127556f4f64592b11af22de27a7932", "became_member_on": "20180426", "income": 70000}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "8ec6ce2a7e7949b1bf142def7d0e0586", "became_member_on": "20170925", "income": null}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "68617ca6246f4fbc85e91a2a49552598", "became_member_on": "20171002", "income": null}
{"gender": "M", "age": 65, "id": "389bc3fa690240e798340f5a15918d5c", "became_member_on": "20180209", "income": 53000}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "8974fc5686fe429db53ddde067b88302", "became_member_on": "20161122", "income": null}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "c4863c7985cf408faee930f111475da3", "became_member_on": "20170824", "income": null}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "148adfcaa27d485b82f323aaaad036bd", "became_member_on": "20150919", "income": null}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stream_in`

```
out <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(str1))
str(out)
#'data.frame':  7 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ gender          : chr  "M" NA NA "M" ...
# $ age             : int  68 118 118 65 118 118 118
# $ id              : chr  "e2127556f4f64592b11af22de27a7932" "8ec6ce2a7e7949b1bf142def7d0e0586" "68617ca6246f4fbc85e91a2a49552598" "389bc3fa690240e798340f5a15918d5c" ...
# $ became_member_on: chr  "20180426" "20170925" "20171002" "20180209" ...
# $ income          : int  70000 NA NA 53000 NA NA NA
```

If we are reading from a file

```
out <- jsonlite::stream_in(file('yourfile.json'))
```

Or with `ndjson::stream_in`

```
out <- ndjson::stream_in('yourfile.json', 'tbl')
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '{"gender": "M", "age": 68, "id": "e2127556f4f64592b11af22de27a7932", "became_member_on": "20180426", "income": 70000}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "8ec6ce2a7e7949b1bf142def7d0e0586", "became_member_on": "20170925", "income": null}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "68617ca6246f4fbc85e91a2a49552598", "became_member_on": "20171002", "income": null}
{"gender": "M", "age": 65, "id": "389bc3fa690240e798340f5a15918d5c", "became_member_on": "20180209", "income": 53000}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "8974fc5686fe429db53ddde067b88302", "became_member_on": "20161122", "income": null}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "c4863c7985cf408faee930f111475da3", "became_member_on": "20170824", "income": null}
{"gender": null, "age": 118, "id": "148adfcaa27d485b82f323aaaad036bd", "became_member_on": "20150919", "income": null}'
```